# Google API - Object.defineProperty called on non-object

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-image-search

I am very new to using APIs, I am trying to return a value for an image search.[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/TheCodingSmith/pen/WjMaVd?editors=1010)

I am trying to get the value of `thumbnailLink` in the array setup like this:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "image": {

    "thumbnailLink": "https://......"
```

[Link to Array](https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyCa8fDiJvEU6G3gYF9wQJiRRVp0eOXajGg&cx=006271532646749467732:ui1nmvdw2ba&searchType=image&q=test)

This is my JavaScript

```
  $.getJSON(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyCa8fDiJvEU6G3gYF9wQJiRRVp0eOXajGg&cx=006271532646749467732:ui1nmvdw2ba&searchType=image&q=" +
      image,
    function(google) {
      var html = "";
      var theImage = $.data(google.items[0].image.thumbnailLink);

      $("#test");
      google.forEach(function(val) {
        var keys = Object.keys(val);
        html += "<img src=";
        keys.forEach(function(key) {
          html += theImage;
        });
        html += ">";
      });
    }
  );
},
```

It is not returning anything, and giving me this error in the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `$.data` method, can tell me why you're using that?

I am providing you a working link of your code: [pen of demo code](http://codepen.io/MehulJoshi/pen/xdYebR?).